# What is the noun that represents the act a "spectator" passively performs in portuguese?

Tags: português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

So, I was writing a document and wanted to use a noun that could represent the act of spectating something.

For example, you can say `expectador` if someone waits for the occurrence of some thing. The act of expectation is called `expectação`, or `expectativa` (expectation in english). You wait for an event to happen, by belief or based on an educated guess.

Now, someone that watches or spectates an event is called `espectador`. As I understand, a spectator beholds an event; he passively experiences said event or receives information in a passive way. It is not an act of waiting, but an act of (passive) engagement with an event.

To my surprise, the noun `espectação` is not listed in any official portuguese dictionary, and most of the sites I found marks it as a misspelling of `expectação`.

So, my question is: Am I correct on my thinking about the two terms/concepts? Either way, what is the correct noun in this case?

---

**EDIT**: Rephrasing my question a bit, because I think I kind of lost the focus of my main issue here.

So, I have these two concepts, that now I'm aware they are different, but for one of them the corresponding noun does not exist:

- Adjective `Expectador`, verb `Expectar`: There is the substantive `Expectação`, and I can find its definition in dictionaries.
- Adjective `Espectador`, verb `Espectar`: There should be the substantive `Espectação`, with `S`, but it does not seem to exist nor be defined anywhere.

So, what is the correct (or equivalent) word for `Espectação`?

Comment: mais perto que chega dessa palavra seria contemplação

Comment: In English, we don't say the act of spectating. Spectator is a noun, not a verb.   You are confusing Portuguese and English. Expectation and spectator are not the same thing. A spectator **attends** an event: ele assiste ao evento ou acontecimento. Tremenda confusão no seu raciocíno que vem da tradução errada dos conceitos. spectate an event não é inglês. In English, you watch an event.  You attend a play or movie (assistir).

Comment: Na verdade, não sabemos qual é a sua pregunta porque está construída numa base falsa.

Comment: http://www.fap.pr.gov.br/arquivos/File/RevistaCientifica3/10_Robson_Rosseto.pdf ato de asistir ao espetáculo the act of attending an event or experiencing an event.

Comment: Se for para usar uma palavra criada que seja uma que você encontra uso na internet como "presenciação" ou "presenciamento" para visões de fantasmas; mas que poderia se usada no lugar de "espectação"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quiseres usar ***espectação*** no sentido de ‘ato de assistir a um espetáculo’, não serás o primeiro a fazê-lo. A palavra não vem nos dicionários, mas já foi usada com este sentido algumas vezes em textos académicos. Eis alguns exemplos (negrito meu):

> Este artigo busca examinar a relação da arquitetura dos cinemas de rua que existiram na Tijuca, Zona Norte do Rio de Janeiro, e as experiências de **espectação cinematográfica** de pessoas que frequentavam essas salas de exibição.
>   [(Talitha Ferraz, *Entre Arquiteturas e Imagens em Movimento: Cinemas, Corporeidades e Espectação Cinematográfica na Tijuca,* UERJ, 2010.)](http://www.e-publicacoes.uerj.br/index.php/logos/article/view/549)
>
> O presente artigo propõe o uso do conceito de “espetacularidade” de Jean Marie Pradier, não para avaliar a **espectação da obra pronta**, mas para análise do processo de criação da cena cinematográfica.
>   [(Pedro Isaias Lucas, *Espetacularidade, Teatralidade e Cinema,* UFRGS, 2012.)](http://www.portalabrace.org/viicongresso/completos/etnocenologia/PEDRO_ISAIAS_LUCAS_-_ESPETACULARIDADE__TEATRALIDADE_E_CINEMA.pdf)
>
> Além disso, em resposta à **espectação passiva da TV**, o cinema pretendia possibilitar a “participação” do expectador – claro que da maneira mais cínica: oprimindo-o com o filme.
>   [(Gabriel Menotti, *Arquitetura da Expectação―A construção histórica da Situação Cinema nos espaços de exibição cinematográfica,* UFF.)](http://www.uff.br/ciberlegenda/ciberlegendajulhoartigogabriel.pdf)

A palavra não vir no dicionário não impede o seu uso; ou a língua estagnaria. É uma questão de ver se a palavra é adequada ao objetivo da comunicação, nomeadamente se o leitor vai entender: como a palavra deve ser desconhecida de quase toda a gente, será necessário que o seu significado se entenda pelo contexto. Por exemplo, nas citação acima creio que o significado seria claro para qualquer um.

Além do mais, o verbo correspondente vem no dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003): “*espectar* ‘olhar, assistir, apreciar’”. O Houaiss diz que está obsoleto, mas encontram-se vários exemplos de uso relativamente recentes no [Google Books](https://www.google.pt/search?q=espectar&num=50&lr=lang_pt&tbs=lr:lang_1pt,sbd:1&tbm=bks&ei=qNYIWe6nF4LSUcTgnoAH&start=0&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=662&dpr=1), como [este de 2005](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BZxdAAAAMAAJ&q=espectar&dq=espectar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkyMPU-NHTAhUJOBoKHcTTCEoQ6AEITjAG) ou [este de 1997](https://books.google.pt/books?id=FVIRAAAAYAAJ&q=espectar&dq=espectar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkyMPU-NHTAhUJOBoKHcTTCEoQ6AEIczAM).

E não me parece que exista qualquer outro substantivo para ‘ato de assistir a um espetáculo, ato de espectar’. Ponderei alguma alternativas, *assistência, observação, contemplação,* mas acho-as insatisfatórias. Um espetador **assiste** a um espetáculo, o que sugere *assistência*, mas eu só vi a palavra usada no sentido de ‘ajuda’ ou ‘o conjunto dos espetadores’. *Observação* sugere mais do que simplesmente ‘ver, assistir’; se alguém me dissesse que ia observar um filme, e imaginaria a pessoa muito atenta, a tomar notas, para depois escrever uma crítica ou coisa assim. *Contemplação* sugere olhar demoradamente para uma imagem mais ou menos parada. *Visualização* talvez escape, embora se mais a respeito de visualização individual de páginas na internet. *Espectação* tem ainda assim a vantagem de partilhar a raiz de *espetador* e *espetáculo*

Comment: Boa resposta, só uma coisa: dizes «o a língua estagnaria», mas como a palavra antes existia seguramente a língua perdeu-a por uma razão, seja economia o falta de necessidade (como dizes, não impede o seu uso, mas se não é palavra muita usada, é possível a gente pensar o seu uso ser um erro.

Comment: @guifa, parece-me que *espectar* e *espectação* foram sempre muito raras. Não aparecem nos dicionários antigos (Bulteau 1712, Morais Silva 1789, Domingos Vieira 1872, Cândido de Figueiredo 1899), e os exemplos no Google Books são raros. E por outro lado, afinal encontram-se exemplos recentes de *espectar*. Portanto perdeu-se, mas na transição do latim para o português, tal como imensas outras palavras, muitas das quais reimportadas a partir do renascimento.

Comment: @guifa, vai haver com certeza gente a pensar que *espectação* é erro. O que me parece importante, como já digo na resposta, é que o contexto deixe claro o significado de *espectação* (nomeadamente impedir a confusão com *expectação*). Ainda assim vai haver sempre pessoal que vai criticar.

Comment: Sugestão: audiência

Comment: @Jacinto The OP made a mismosh of everything so his question is not clear and it is based on a basic misunderstanding of terms. Frankly, he mixes up basic terminology. There is no verb spectate in English. For example, he says: the act of expectation is expectação. It simply makes no sense so I took his remarks and commented on them. Someone downvoted me. This is a fool's errand. To attend an event and see it is: assistir ao espectáculo. Everyone just seems to go along with the mismosh. Good luck.

Comment: @Lambie, much of the question is indeed confusing; Flávio himself admits he lost focus of the main issue; but the title plus the edit make clear, to me at least, that he's looking for a word for 'ato de assistir a espetáculo'. I stand by my answer.

Comment: @bfavaretto, *audiência* seria outra possibilidade, mas ponderando os prós e os contras, eu alinharia mesmo com *espectação*; o problema de *audiência*, tal como com *assistência*, é que já tem vários outros significados, e nos dicionários não figura 'ato de assistir'.  Por exemplo, no último exemplo da minha resposta,  *audiência passiva da TV* seria facilmente tomado por 'público passivo da TV'.

Comment: @Jacinto But he didn't lose focus. The question never had any focus. The act of attending a show is merely o ato de asistir a  um espetáculo. Em inglês, não existe o verbo to spectate. Os exemplos dado por você são de outra ordem que a pergunta. Esses "críticos" inventaram esse vocabulário pos-modernista; tudo bem mas nada tem a ver com a pergunta. O ato de asistir também pode ser dito como: **the act of being a spectator**. Em todo caso, essa invenções teriam de ser inventadas em inglês, porque não existem.

Comment: @Labmbie There is indeed the verb *spectate* in English.  Per the OED: "**1.** *intr.* and *trans.* To look or gaze (at). || **2.** *intr.*  [Back-formation < *spectator n.*] To be a spectator rather than a participant, esp. at a sporting event." and also includes the derivative form **spectating** *adj.* and *n* that has the exact meaning that the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A palavra *expetaçāo* vem do latim *expectatio*. Existia sim nele uma palavra *spectatio* (que faria uma palavra hipotética *espetaçāo*) mas aquela não sobreviveu até a modernidade. Tão-pouco fica na língua o verbo do qual derivou (*spectare*) então é mais difícil fazermos um neologismo.

Somente ficaram três palavras que hoje são mais bem fosis, *espetador*, *espetáculo* e *espetacular*. Interessantemente, o acto de «espetar» (que hoje é *ver*) que seria a palavra da que perguntas, também perdeu as outras línguas românicas. Parece que o italiano manteve a palavra mais do que as outras (como *spettazione*) mas não é palavra de uso comum hoje; aliás significava  *testemunho* ou *observação*.

Assim acho que a palavra que melhor descreve a ideia que sugeres seria **visão** ou **observação**.

Comment: Também pensei no mesmo. **Observação** talvez seja uma boa opção no meu caso, pois pretendo aplicar a palavra para qualificar uma atividade. E.g. em um documento, já descrevi o que é uma _Atividade Coletiva_, e agora estou para descrever o que é uma _Atividade de Espectação_ (neste caso, uma atividade com uma platéia, onde uma pessoa vai para ser um espectador).

Comment: a palavra spectator em inglês, em português é: espetador.

Comment: @lambie esse comentário é para mim? Já tenho na minha resposta a palavra *espetador*

Comment: No lugar de visão entraria visualização.

Comment: As pessoas usam "acompanhei uma programa de tv" no sentido de seguir os episódios; daí por semelhança alguns dizem "Acompanhei um programa um show tal", o que não é muito correto mas tem ideia semelhante. Então uma outra sugestão dependendo do caso pode ser a palavra acompanhamento. Participação também, já que espectadores podem ser participantes "participei de um show de rock" no sentido de só estar presente,

Answer (score 0):

Sim, existem dois termos/conceitos.

Primeiro temos o verbo aguardar - "estar a espera de; permanecer na expectativa de; esperar" ou "vigiar, velar, guardar" - segundo o dicionário Aurélio.

O dicionário traz também o termo 'aguardador' que é "aquele que aguarda".

E, finalmente, o substantivo 'aguardo' como "ato ou efeito de aguardar; espera", com o seguinte exemplo: "Estou no aguardo de suas notícias". Neste sentido pode ser usado o termo 'expectador' (com x) "aquele que tem expectativa" - mas seu uso é bastante incomum.

O segundo conceito, que não tem relação com aguardar (esperar, ter expectativa), é o de presenciar, assistir, testemunhar. O termo 'espectador' (com s) é muito utilizado com esse sentido em português e serve para designar aquele que assiste a um espetáculo ou que vê um evento esportivo.

Comment: Entendo, mas a minha segunda pergunta é qual a palavra correta para o caso de espectar, já que "espectação" gramaticalmente não existe (ao que parece)?

Comment: Não consigo pensar em uma palavra que tenha este sentido exato. "Presença" é utilizado para o fato de estar presente. Existe também "testemunho", mas normalmente é usado mais para designar um relato sobre um fato do que o ato de "presenciar" o fato.

Comment: **Presença** pode ser uma boa substituição, no geral. Apenas para que entenda a minha motivação, estou criando um documento que descreve uma sociedade de alunos, e pretendo enumerar os tipos de atividades que iremos exercer. Já descrevi o que é uma _Atividade Coletiva_ (os alunos participam ativamente e em quantidade), e agora estou para descrever o que é uma _Atividade de "Espectação"_ (neste caso, uma atividade com uma platéia, onde um aluno comparece para ser um espectador). Posso até desistir da ideia de caracterizar os tipos de atividade, mas a minha dúvida veio por meio deste contexto.

Comment: Neste caso eu usaria **comparecimento**, mas concordo inteiramente contigo, há perda de significado. Por exemplo, se um aluno estiver assistindo (sendo espectador) a uma aula virtual, o verbo "comparecer" não descreve tão bem a atividade quanto o verbo "assistir".